# Bootstrap responsive menu doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having some problems with the responsive Bootstrap menu, as it won't open (I'm using Bootstrap navwalker for WordPress. I have checked that it loads both jQuery and the Bootstrap JS, which it does.

**The code**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>">Tandklinikken<br/> Østerbro</a>
            </div>
            <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu'              => 'primary',
                    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                    'depth'             => 2,
                    'container'         => 'div',
                    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                );
            ?>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Here's a [link](http://www.tandklinikkenoesterbro.dk/) for the website.

Comment: Post up the relevant part of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

Your `data-target` at button is different.You need to have `#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1` instead of `#navbar`

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>">Tandklinikken<br/> Østerbro</a>
        </div>
        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
        ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Give an explanation, pls.